# Running web application on another localhost

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, web, localhost

I have a ASP.NET C# web application with database. On my localhost it works fine. I have attached my database on my local SQL server. If I like my application to run on another machine's localhost ,do I have to change only connection string or I have to attach database on the another localhost server .

Comment: you will need to create the database on the other localhost server.

Comment: What do you mean by "localhost"? If you want both instances of your application to share the database you should NOT use "localhost" but a named host address or ip.

Comment: No I don't want both instances to share the same database, I only want to test my application on another localhost machine

Answer (score 2):

*another machine's localhost*

This phrase is not correct by itself. In networking "localhost" refers to the current computer's ip address. So if you use "localhost" as a name of sql server it will always look for a server on a local computer. So if you move your application to another computer you have to whether move your database to that computer too (and then you can keep localhost or (local) as a server name) or you can keep the database where it is but then you need to use real computer's name or ip address so that your service can find the database.